# HTML list formatting

Tags: html, css

New to CSS.  I tried to create a cascaded bullets. Turned out the style for li, ul were overwritten by some css file, I had to manually add `style="list-style-type: disc;"` to get back the bullet.
However the following HTML code doesn't produce the nested bullets with identations.

```
    this is an example
    <ul>
        <li style="list-style-type: disc;"> this 1
            <ul>
                <li style="list-style-type: disc;"> this is 1.1</li>
                <li style="list-style-type: disc;"> this is 1.2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
```

Here is what it looks on my browser

[image]

Any idea how to make the nested list with indentation by applying the right styles on the ul and li elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's ok for me http://jsbin.com/wodikate/1/edit... the problem is in some where else... would you add whole code?

Comment: works fine [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZFKjj/). your other `css` code might overide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example, I have made it very close to your case:

http://jsfiddle.net/MUNP9/

The idea is that some CSS in the page is overriding default `padding-left` of the nested `ul`. You can override it again.

Like:

```
ul ul {
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Also, you don't need to apply inline styles, just use CSS classes.

Comment: Previous comment didn't seem to make it, here is it again.   Thanks! It helped.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have conflicting styles. You may want to try a CSS resetter. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/